# Swift Core Data - Update objects connected to a individual user

Tags: swift, core-data, relationship

In my core data I have two tables "user" and "course" which are connected in a many-to-many relationship. Users are able to add/register courses to their account via .addCourseToList() however when I try to update a course object in a certain user's courselist with course.hasStarted = true the changes are applied to the course itself and to all users and not the individual who made the changes.

adding course to user:

```
    func addToWishlist(course: Course) {
    signedInUser.addToWishlist(course)
    DataManager.shared.saveContext()
}
```

retrieving a users courses:

```
if let bought = signedInUser.bought?.allObjects as? [Course]{
        allCourses.append(bought)
    }
```

make changes:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let course = allCourses[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    print(course.progression)
    if course.progression >= 1.0 {
        course.progression = 1.0
    } else {
        course.progression += 0.1
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
    DataManager.shared.saveContext()
}
```

[database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhKr6.png)

Comment: This sounds right if several users are taking the same course, when the course starts it starts for everyone taking the course. If you want to make this individual then you either need to make this into a many-to-one relationship or add a 3rd entity that keeps track of if/when a specific course starts for each user (that is some kind of schedule or calendar)

Comment: Your data model diagram doesn't include a `hasStarted` attribute.

Comment: But isn't that what I'm doing with a many-to-many relationship between users and courses.